# Division properties

Tags: arithmetic

Proportionally scaling up or down division terms (antecedent|numerator|dividend & consequent|denominator|divisor) doesn't change the end result (fraction|quotient). Is there a name for this property?

ex:

10/5 = 2

after scaling up both terms

100/50 = 2

Comment: Can you give an example? Can I take $\frac{1}{2}$ for "division term"? The what exactly? That $\frac{a\cdot 1}{a\cdot 2}=\frac{1}{2}$? This is cancelling. Or "reduce fractions". Yes $10/5=2$ is to reduce fractions.

Comment: Maybe the term you are after is "scale invariance"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancelling_out

Comment: [Homogeneous of degree $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function). Also, if you have some introductory differential equations background, then you may have seen the topic [homogeneous first-order differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_first-order_differential_equations).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you